# Javascript: Array is not empty but size is 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I create a array in Javascript. I want to use the array for key-value pair.

I can successfully add new items and delete items but the length of it is always 0.

Actually the problem I faced is when I want to convert it to a JSON string, it shows empty string: "[]". I just wonder if they are related. And I would also want to know why I cannot convert it.

Below is the debug information, It show the array contain 3 objects but the length is 0. The browser is Firefox 44.0 for Ubuntu.

Thanks!

[image: Array with length <code>0</code> and properties <code>1454073967313</code>, <code>1454073968645</code>, and <code>1454073969737</code>]

---

Fellow @georg idea, I limited the index into 1000 and leave the rest code as before. Everything works including the JSON part.
The next picture shows that in my array, there are actual 4 elements, the maximum index is 805.

[image]

### One thing I learned is that the length of Javascript Array is not the real size but the maximum index number.

The newest finding, the array is really as long as the largest index number. The rest of the element is Null.

Comment: I think you're better using an object than an array, can you please post the object structure?

Comment: How are you adding the items? We can't tell you why it's not working if you don't let us see where you're going wrong.

Comment: `objectsinfo` should be an [object (`{}`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) instead of an [array (`[]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Hey, what's up with DVs? This is a good question.

Comment: @georg the question originally didn't have the image included inline, which was integral to the understanding the problem, without sufficient any explanation in the text. (Of course, the OP *couldn't* include the image, lacking sufficient rep to do so.) With the image included, it's indeed a very nice question now.

Comment: While you *can* use an array for this with lower indexes, you definitely *shouldn't*, and should use an object instead. The JSON `{"805":{ ... }` is *many hundreds of times* shorter than `[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,...,{ ... }]`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one of many oddities in javascript.

```
> a = []
[]
> a[4294967295] = 1
1
> a.length
0 // wtf?
```

The problem is that `Array.length` is limited to 32 bits, so its max value is `2^32-1 = 4294967295`. If you provide an index greater than or equal to `4294967295`, the engine creates a new entry in the array, as usual, but refuses to update its `length` - without throwing any error. So you end up with a bag of properties, and the `length` equal to 0.

As others suggested, you will be better off using objects if you have such large numeric indexes.

Comment: That is the correct answer! Thanks! Sorry I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Comment: @PingjiangLi: glad to hear it helped. Don't worry about the reps.